# Bridal shower and Baby shower, what does that even mean?

Tags: american-english, expressions

In

> A few years ago I hosted a bridal shower at your restaurant and it was fantastic! I'm going to be hosting a baby shower in September and would love to have it at Jane's!

What does `bridal shower` and `baby shower` mean in this context?

Comment: [*shower*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shower) (Def 5) A party associated with a significant event in a person's life, at which the person usually receives gifts.

Comment: I was taught the word gets its name because the bride-to-be (or mother-to-be) gets _showered_ with gifts. At many showers, the gifts are designed to help the woman transition to her new life. So, for a baby shower, most of the gifts will be things a mom will need for her new baby: perhaps a crib, a diaper bag, a baby swing, some baby clothes, etc. Instead of the new mom incurring all those expenses, her friends _shower_ her with many of those items as gifts.

Comment: this is as much sociology than English but it's worth mentioning that (as is explained in the accepted answer) showers are typically parties celebrating women -- i.e. you don't call it a shower if you throw a party for a man getting married

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *shower* is quite commonly used in North America.

> [shower (North American English)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/shower) -a party at which you give presents to a woman who is getting married or having a baby.

In particular,

> [baby shower](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/baby-shower) - a party given for a woman who is going to have a baby, at which her friends give her presents for the baby. 
>   [bridal shower](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bridal-shower) - a party for a woman who will soon be getting married, at which she receives presents

Comment: Thanks I was imagining that they would bath the baby first time I saw it.

Comment: @JonathandeM. Nope, it's something like blessings or gifts falling on them as water falls in shower.